# ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" when running sql script via psql | pgAdmin | PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin, pg-dump

I'm facing an issue while performing a pg_dump of an existing database into two SQL files.

- One file is intended for a schema-only dump.
- The other is for a data-only dump

The command for the schema-only dump executes successfully using the following command:

> psql -u dbuser -d empDatabase -f C:\SchemaOnlyDump.sql

However, the **data-only dump** encounters an error, specifically,**ERROR: syntax error at or near '\.'**

> psql -u dbuser -d empDatabase -f C:\DataOnlyDump.sql

The data-only dump file has the following content:

[image]

Looks like PostgreSQL is interpreting the '.' symbol as part of SQL syntax whereas it serves a special purpose within the context of COPY commands executed in '**psql**'

How can I execute the data-only SQL to populate the data into the database?

Comment: That copy command is missing essential parts. It does neither copy FROM somewhere, nor TO - so what's it even supposed to do?

Comment: (See the snytax of PostgreSQL copy command in the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html )

Comment: How was the dump generated? If you use, for instance, `pg_dumpall`, the first line of the generated command would be `COPY employee (empid, name, position) FROM stdin;`.

Comment: Are you getting this issue running the script through `psql` or `pgAdmin4`?  I have seen issues with `pgAdmin` and `COPY`.  I routinely run data only dumps that use `COPY` through `psql` with no issue. **Add to your question text** the complete error message as text(not as an image).

Comment: Then feeding `C:\data-only-dump.sql` to `psql` should not be an issue. Verify what @ÁlvaroGonzález mentioned.